# Using event handlers on document before the DOM is loaded

Tags: jquery

Would it be ok to add an `ajaxStop()` event handler to the `document` before the DOM is loaded? It isn't related to any DOM elements, so as far as I can tell it shouldn't matter. Am I right?

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    console.log('ajax complete');     
});
```

vs

```
$(function(){

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        console.log('ajax complete');     
    });

});
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: @Blazemonger It didn't cause any errors on my test page (which is almost empty). I'm asking to make sure that it won't cause a problem later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(function(){})` is actually shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

So, by using `$(function(){})` you *already* are binding an event to `document` before the DOM is ready.

By that logic, it's fine to bind `ajaxStop` to `document` before the DOM is ready.